# How to import a C++ dll in Matlab

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, dllimport

I'm struggling with the importation of C++ (2017) dlls in Matlab (2019a).

In particular, since I'm not familiar with C++, I tried to create the MathLibrary defined in https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp.md.
I created the library according to the guide, compiled both Debug and Release (x86), and the import with the MathClient described works fine.

However, I tried to import the library in Matlab (after adding the needed folders to the current path) with:

```
        if libisloaded('MathLibrary') == 0
           handle = loadlibrary('MathLibrary.dll','MathLibrary.h');
        end
```

and it throws a tons of errors:

```
        Warning: Message from C preprocessor:
        cl : command line warning D9027: source file 'C:\Users\miche\source\repos\MathLibrary\Release\MathLibrary.lib' ignored
        cl : command line warning D9021 : no operation performed

        > In loadlibrary 
        Error loading library intermediate output follows.
        The actual error is at the end of this output.
        *********
        Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated here (and will be fatal in Perl 5.30), passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/struct([^;,{(]*){ <-- HERE (.*?)\}([^;])*;/ at D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\matlab\general\private\prototypes.pl line 912.
        Warning no reference to header 'MathLibrary' added with addheader was found in source.
        *********
        Error using loadlibrary
        Building MathLibrary_thunk_pcwin64 failed.  Compiler output is:
        cl -I"D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\include" /Zp8  /W3
        /nologo  -I"D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin"
        -I"C:\Users\user\source\repos\MathLibrary\Release"
        "MathLibrary_thunk_pcwin64.c" -LD
        -Fe"MathLibrary_thunk_pcwin64.dll"
        MathLibrary_thunk_pcwin64.c
        C:\Users\miche\source\repos\MathLibrary\Release\MathLibrary.lib(1):
        error C2059: syntax error: '!'
        C:\Users\miche\source\repos\MathLibrary\Release\MathLibrary.lib(2):
        error C2018: character '0x60' unknown
```

and then it just goes on like this, with a lot of character errors.
What is wrong with my code? How do I solve this?

Comment: In my experience, a mex file is a better choice than loadlibrary

Comment: You probably want to use `NET.addAssembly('Somewhere\On\Your\PC\MathLibrary.dll')`

Comment: There are two problems: (1) `loadlibrary` wants the header file as 2nd argument, not the import library. The header file is a text file that describes the functions in the library to the compiler. (2) `loadlibrary` is described to load C libraries, not C++ libraries. It might work for C++, but I wouldn’t hold my breath. Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html)!

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks, I corrected the first problem. About the second one, my problems came from the fact that in the documentation is written that 'Functions written in C++ must be declared as extern "C".', as they are in the MathLibrary I created, but still I have these errors.

Comment: The error message specifically says that it cannot parse “MathLibrary.lib” as a text file. If you changed your code as in your edit, your error message must have changed too. Please post the new error message you get. Also post a minimal version of the header file. Please see [mre] to learn how to make such a minimal version.